# Deriving boundary conditions at a surface of discontinuity: $\int \mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{n} \ dS = 0$

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, physics, electromagnetism, divergence-theorem

I am currently studying *Principles of Optics: Electromagnetic Theory of Propagation, Interference and Diffraction of Light*, 7th edition, by Max Born and Emil Wolf. Chapter **1.1.3 Boundary conditions at a surface of discontinuity** says the following:

> Let us replace the sharp discontinuity surface $T$ by a thin transition layer within which $\epsilon$ and $\mu$ vary rapidly but continuously from their values near $T$ on one side to their value near $T$ on the other. Within this layer we construct a small near-cylinder, bounded by a stockade of normals to $T$; roofed and floored by small area $\delta A_1$ and $\delta A_2$ on each side of $T$, at constant distance from it, measured along their common normal (Fig. 1.1). Since $\mathbf{B}$ and its derivatives may be assumed to be continuous throughout this cylinder, we may apply Gauss's theorem to the integral of $\text{div} \ \mathbf{B}$ taken throughout the volume of the cylinder and obtain, from (4),
> $$\int \text{div} \ \mathbf{B} \ dV = \int \mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{n} \ dS = 0; \tag{12}$$
> the second integral is taken over the surface of the cylinder, and $\mathbf{n}$ is the unit outward normal.
> Since the area $\delta A_1$ and $\delta A_2$ are assumed to be small, $\mathbf{B}$ may be considered to have constants values $\mathbf{B}^{(1)}$ and $\mathbf{B}^{(2)}$ on $\delta A_1$ and $\delta A_2$, and (12) may then be replaced by
> $$\mathbf{B}^{(1)} \cdot \mathbf{n}_1 \delta A_1 + \mathbf{B}^{(2)} \cdot \mathbf{n}_2 \delta A_2 + \text{contribution from walls} = 0 \tag{13}$$
> [image]

$\epsilon$ is the dielectric constant (or permittivity).
$\mu$ is the magnetic permeability.
$\mathbf{B}$ is the magnetic induction.
(4) is the relation $\text{div} \ \mathbf{B} = 0$.

Why does the area $\delta A_1$ and $\delta A_2$ being small imply that $\mathbf{B}$ may be considered to have constants values $\mathbf{B}^{(1)}$ and $\mathbf{B}^{(2)}$ on $\delta A_1$ and $\delta A_2$? It almost seems like the terms $\mathbf{B}^{(k)} \cdot \mathbf{n}_k \delta A_k$ are some height times area calculation.

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: I think that there is a cause-effect fallacy in you reasoning.
It is usually said that the area $\delta A$ is such (small enough) that vector $\mathbf{B}$ is constant over that area.

Comment: @Caran-d'Ache Can you please elaborate on what it actually means for $\mathbf{B}$ to be constant over that area? I mean, if the cylinder is uniform, then isn't it superfluous to say that $\mathbf{B}$ is constant? I mean, why would $\mathbf{B}$ *not* be constant?

Comment: It's not necessarily constant. Note that by hypothesis the magnetic field is continuous, and the normal vector field to the cylinder also varies continuously, so their dot product is also continuous. Continuity (roughly) means that over a sufficiently small domain, the value of a function (in this case the dot product of B and n) doesn't change by much. This is the key idea being used. To make this argument more precise you would have to look more closely at the (epsilon delta) definition of continuity. Or, you can try to apply the mean-value theorem for integrals along with continuity.

Comment: On a slightly related note, you may want to take a look [at this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/407129/203278) for a slightly more precise argument (though I haven't looked carefully at each step there, it seems promising, and the ideas there can probably be adapted to work here)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks for the input. So, if I'm understanding you correctly, since we have the *infinitesimal* areas $\delta A_1$ and $\delta A_2$, the domain is "sufficiently small" that $\mathbf{B}$ is (or can be considered to be) constant (that is, has constant values $\mathbf{B}^{(1)}$ and $\mathbf{B}^{(2)}$)?

Comment: yes that's the rough idea. This boils down entirely to the fact that $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{n}$ are continuous by assumption.

Comment: @peek-a-boo ok, thanks for taking the time to clarify this for me.